# ALB, send request to next server if backend server responds with 502

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Is there a way to route request to another EC2 server in autoscaling group if EC2 server responds with a 502 status code.

Only by using AWS ALB ?

Answer (score 0):

ALB will divide traffic over instances deemed healthy. Due to [any number of reasons](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html) an ALB may output a 502 response. If you wish to re-enter this request then you will need custom logic between the ALB and the source of the request. I would suggest either looking at the cause of the 502, which more often than not is a structural problem, or somehow incorporate a suitable health check that could help deregistering the instance and preventing traffic from being sent to it in the first place.